# Getting "unknown time zone America/Ciudad_Juarez" when try to call LoadLocation in golang 1.17.6

Tags: go, time

I retrieve timezones from different locations, using time.LoadLocation(tz) which provides all the time information with some extra metadata. Everything works except America/Ciudad_Juarez.

This simple code:

```
import (
    "time"
)

loc, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Ciudad_Juarez")
    if err != nil {
        println(err)
    }
```

Getting an error saying "unknown time zone America/Ciudad_Juarez".
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74820972/chrome-intl-cant-handle-america-ciudad-juarez sounds like that's a relatively new identifier.  If you don't have it on your system you may need to update your system's zone info

Answer (score 1):

[America/Ciudad_Juarez was introduced on 2022-11-29](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tzdb/NEWS) (Release 2022g). Your system's timezone database is older than that. Either update it (the package is typically called tzdata), or import time/tzdata to use the timezone database shipped with Go. Note that Go 1.17 is from 2021, so the built-in database is well out of date by now also. You should definitely update to a supported version of Go.

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
        _ "time/tzdata" // use built-in timezone database
)

func main() {
        _, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Ciudad_Juarez")
        fmt.Println(err) // <nil>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

America/Ciudad_Juarez is relatively newer timezone.

LoadLocation searches for timezones in given order and location

```
// LoadLocation looks for the IANA Time Zone database in the following
// locations in order:
//
//   - the directory or uncompressed zip file named by the ZONEINFO environment variable
//   - on a Unix system, the system standard installation location
//   - $GOROOT/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip
//   - the time/tzdata package, if it was imported
```

You can download the latest one from 1.22(at the time of writing) Go version repo: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip

download and replace `$GOROOT/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip` with newly downloaded file.